# Graphics driver for Ubuntu on Dell Latitude XT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers

we have a Dell Latitude XT laptop in our company, and we would like to install Ubuntu on it. Windows 7 works fine out of the box, so the hardware is fine.

Since this laptop has a touchscreen we just installed Ubuntu 10.10 netbook edition 32-bit. But we did not manage to enable either the touchscreen or the VGA graphic drivers.

This is the output of running `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Xpress 7930 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS7932 PCI Bridge
00:04.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Device 7934
00:06.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS7936 PCI Bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Device 7937
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Xpress 1250
03:01.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
03:01.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
03:01.3 SD Host controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5756ME Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03)
```

I've tried to install ATI drivers 9.3, which I downloaded and installed, unpacked and installed, built and installed, but nothing worked. Looks like the latest version is just accepted to work on Jaunty 9.04, so they are kind of old.

What else I can do?

Information added: `lsusb` and `lspci -n |grep 01:05.0`

```
sysop@wl083517:~$ lspci -n |grep 01:05.0
01:05.0 0300: 1002:7942
sysop@wl083517:~$ lsusb 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 413c:8138 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 5520 Voda I Mobile Broadband (3G HSDPA) Minicard EAP-SIM Port
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 413c:8140 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 360 Bluetooth
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint Reader
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1b96:0001 N-Trig Duosense Transparent Electromagnetic Digitizer
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03f0:1807 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
sysop@wl083517:~$
```

Comment: I forgot to say that aticonfig always says the same:
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected

Comment: Post the output of `lsusb`, as well as the output of `lspci -n` for `01:05.0`.

Comment: This may get more responses on superuser.com :)

Comment: Bryan , how do I move it there? I guess cut and paste it's quite dirty, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

That card *is* apparently supported by the [`radeon`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/radeon) driver (the man page linked to is slightly obsolete), but that specific PCI ID *may* be missing. Try forcing it using a `ChipID` directive in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

As for the touchscreen, it appears that [changing the driver](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=240223) will do it.

Comment: There is a bug reported affecting this graphic card. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/558378

Comment: That's a problem with the kernel module though, not the Xorg driver.